# Failure to initialize new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, initialization

I created a model that looks like the following:

```
class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company, :stock_ticker, :current_stock_price, :free_cash_flow, :num_shares, :PE_ratio, :dividend_per_share, :dividend_growth_rate, :beta, :cost_of_equity, :rate_of_return, :fcf_share_value, :capm_share_value, :dividend_share_value, :composite_share_value  

  def initialize(submitted_stock)
    @company = submitted_stock
    @stock_ticker = submitted_stock
    @current_stock_price = 0 
    @free_cash_flow = 0
    @num_shares = 0 
    @PE_ratio = 0
    @dividend_per_share = 0
    @dividend_growth_rate = 0
    @beta = 0
    @cost_of_equity = 0
    @rate_of_return = 0
    @fcf_share_value = 0
    @capm_share_value = 0
    @dividend_share_value = 0
    @composite_share_value = 0
  end
end
```

When I try to create a new `Stock`:

```
s = Stock.new("MSFT")
```

no new stock is created, and instead, I get the following response:

```
#<Stock not initialized>
```

I used Pry and saw that it is assigning the values to the instance variables, but it isn't initializing the object or creating it.

Comment: Is there any more details about the error.

Answer (score 3):

You are overriding `ActiveRecord`s `initialize` method. That's probably going to cause problems - especially if you change the interface (as you have).

A better way is probably to set your defaults using an [`after_initialize` callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Or if you insist on defining your own `initialize` make sure you call `ActiveRecord`s ditto using `super`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't in general override `initialize` for Active Record objects. In addition active record attributes are not stored in individual instance variables so setting all those instance variables to zero doesn't achieve anything